# Function.call taking array-like object , doesnt require the first parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

So,  I couldn t find out how Function.call doesnt have to take the first argument as an object as I couldn t find such an information anywhere. Although I have seen hundreds of usage of Function.call like the next line of code, taking only this array-like object, NOT REQUIRING THE FIRST PARAMETER AS AN OBJECT, SINCE IT TAKES ARGUMENTS OF FUNCTION WHICH IS AN ARRAY-LIKE OBJECT. It works of course.

```
argsSliced = Array.prototype.slice.call((function(){return arguments;})(1,2,3,4))
```

Although next lines of codes behaves as we expect, requiring the first parameter to be an object to set this of function to that object and requires parameters to pass to function after that object.

```
var a = function(){return arguments[0] + arguments[1] ; }
console.log(a.call(1,2)); // returns NaN
console.log(a.call(null,1,2)); // behaves as we expect, returns 3
```

So my question, what is the situation with the array-like object ? How does it work with the Function.call as it doesn t give it an object as a first parameter but only gives an array-like object.

Comment: What is your question? In the first `argSliced` example, you are passing the arguments pseudo-array as the first (and only) parameter to `call`, so it becomes the `this` to `slice`. In the second example, in `a.call(1,2)`, you are passing `1` as this to `a`, `2` as the first parameter, and nothing as the second parameter, so `arguments[1]` is undefined and you get NaN. In the following call, you are passing null as this to `a`, `1` as the first parameter, and `2` as the second parameter, so it returns 3, obviously.

Comment: Look at the expression `function(){return arguments;})(1, 2, 3, 4)`, which is what is being passed as the first parameter to `call`, and thus the `this` to `slice`. It invokes the anonymous function with the parameters `(1, 2, 3, 4)`, which therefore returns an arguments (array-like) object containing `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by saying "`this` is not passed to slice". The first argument to `Array.prototype.slice.call` becomes the `this` for `slice`. In your second example, you are not using `this` at all. `slice` and `a` are fundamentally different because `slice` operates on the `this` array or array-like object, whereas `a` has no `this`.

Comment: I know that because that's how `call` works. The first argument becomes the `this` for the invoked function. There are no exceptions for anything.

Comment: **There IS an object parameter as the first parameter to be this for the function in your first example**. `function() { return arguments; }(1, 2, 3, 4)` **IS** an object.

Comment: I got confused, sorry for the drama. Thanks for the help. So my question is not a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN for call() explains it clearly:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

> The value of `this` provided for the call to function. Note that this may not
>   be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in
>   **non-strict mode** code, **null and undefined will be replaced with the
>   global object** and primitive values will be converted to objects.

```
var a = function(){return arguments[0] + arguments[1] ; }
console.log(a.call(1,2));
```

arguments[1] will be `undefined` ,and 2 will be `arguments[0]` because 1 will be boxed to an object.

remember `f.call(ob,4);` is like saying `ob.f(4)`

Comment: please explain the downvote, if i did something wrong at least let me know

Comment: But OP is calling `call` with an object as the first argument, not a primitive. I don't see how this relates to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This function, when called, returns an array-like Arguments object with the arguments

```
var f = function(){return arguments;};
```

Then, when you call it with arguments `1`,`2`,`3` and `4`,

```
f(1,2,3,4) // Arguments [1,2,3,4]
```

Then, you call `Function.prototype.call` on `Array.prototype.slice`, passing that Arguments object as the argument.

So `Function.prototype.call` will call `Array.prototype.slice` with the `this` value set to the Arguments object (instead of `Array.prototype`), and no arguments.

When `Array.prototype.slice` is called on an array-like object, it builds a real array from that object. So you get

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(f(1,2,3,4)); // Array [1,2,3,4]
```

Note there are better ways to achieve this:

```
Array.of(1,2,3,4)
Array(1,2,3,4)
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got confused and this is not a valid question. Sorry for the trouble.